# Trying to show the total price of a grouped product in view page simultaneously on selection of qty in Magento

Tags: jquery, html, magento

I'm try to display the total price of a grouped product on selection of the quantities, which simultaneously updates the price in total as shown in the picture. The issue I'm currently facing is, I'm able to see the updated the total price. But the price value is not appropriate. And It is considering only one item price i.e; the price remains the same and and calculating the total price. Please help me, How can I do this. Thanks in Advance:)

And the code is below;

```
 <table class="data-table grouped-items-table" id="super-product-table">
<col />
<col />
<col width="1" />
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
        <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
        <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <th class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
<?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
    <?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_item, $_item->getFinalPrice(), true) ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></td>
        <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
        <td class="a-right">
            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <td class="a-center">
        <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
            <input type="text" name="super_group[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>]" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $_item->getQty()*1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="txt" />
            <input type="hidden" name="myprice" maxlength="12" id="myprice" value="<?php echo $_item->getPrice() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('') ?>" class="myprice" />
        <?php else: ?>
            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <tr><div class="myprice" style="display:none;"><?php echo $_item->getPrice() ?></div></tr>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
   <tr>
       <td colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('No options of this product are available.') ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endif; ?>

<tr id="summation">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right"><strong style=""> Total Price: </strong></td>
    <td align="center"><strong><span id="sum">0</span></strong></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".txt").each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            var price = $('.myprice').html();
            calculateSum(price);
        });
    });

});

function calculateSum(price) {
    var sum = 0;

    $(".txt").each(function() {
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum = sum + price * parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });

    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem (if i understand correctly, not 100% sure).

```
$(this).keyup(function(){
        var price = $('.myprice').html();
        calculateSum(price);
    });
```

You have this code. I'm assuming that myprice is a class on the txt element? so you would need to do like :

```
$(this).find('.myprice').html();
```

What you are doing, will find ALL my price classes. Hope this helps

Comment: In grouped product page, I'm trying to display the total product price below the child products. the total product price will be displayed based on the entered qty. For ex: child Items; price1+qty1 = 20; price2+qty2= 30 then the total price will be 50, should be displayed.  I'm trying the same to display the total price of grouped product on entering qty. But the computation only considers first item price, irrespective of all the item.

Comment: Can you post your html please.

Comment: I have updated the html content in the post. Here I'm trying to modify the default/template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml file.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I wasnt able to access here over the weekend

Comment: No Problem Benderman. But I really appreciate your supportive nature :)

Comment: but what is the answer? @SKumar how you can made that?